# Is there a way to find if the a git commit was a clean merge commit through the GitHub API?

Tags: git, github, github-api

We are automating certain github flows in our organisation and are building some tools using the public GitHub API.

We would like to find if a merge commit was a clean merge or if it had conflicts that were resolved.

If you look [here](https://github.com/MarcoIeni/release-plz/pull/421/commits/dac336c354eca7e1bd32a3bb6405ac4087939a31) at the UI github clearly has some mechanism to find out if a merge was a clean merge. So, I assume this is possible, please let me know how?

Also attaching a screenshot of the link
[image]

Comment: That link doesn't say if the commit was clean or not?

Comment: added an of what i see, it says "the merge commit was added into this branch cleanly"